# Refactor Nested FlatMap in RxJS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs, flatmap

I have a `itemsObservable`, `filtersObservable`, and a `queryObservable` and feed their values to a function that takes a list of items, filter conditions, and a search query, and returns a filtered list.

Right now my code looks something like:

```
itemsObservable
    .flatMap(items => {
        filtersObservable
            .flatMap(filters => {
                queryObservable
                    .map(query => filterItems(items, filters, query))
             })
     });
```

Is there a better code pattern for this that eschews the deep nesting?

Answer (score 1):

```
queryObservable.withLatestFrom(
    filtersObservable,
    itemsObservable,
    (query, filters, items) => filterItems(items, filters, query)
)
```